# Data channels and remote streams in WebRTC

Tags: video, stream, webrtc

I am trying to build an application which allows making voice/ video calls, and also sending voice messages. When using WebRTC, remote streams will be used for voice/ video calls. 
However, can I use datachannel for sending only voice messages - i.e. in the absence of any ongoing call, my users could send recorded voice messages over datachannel, instead of having to establish remote streams for voice messages. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

I would use the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). When you have your media recorded you can send anything you want via your DataChannel.

Make sure to construct a reliable/ordered datachannel, and you should also check the backpressure to make sure the entire audio file has been transferred.

Comment: Thank you Sean! What is the preferred method of sending voice/ video messages - remote streams or data channels?
Also, could you share any webpage which shows the use of WebRTC "data channel" for sending voice messages , instead of using remote streams.